# handling notifications on app launch before the app fully loads

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am having some trouble with the loading sequence at the launch of my app.

My device is receiving a remote notification while the app is inactive. I am handling that in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. I get the notification from the launchOptions, and then I produce a NotificationCenter notification, which gets handled in my view controller.

In the view controller, the method handling the notification is meant to make some changes to the ui, including modifying the layout of some components and calling a javascript loaded in a UIWebView.

This last part never happens, since multiple items that need to be modified, including the loading of the page into the UIWebView happens in my viewDidLoad, which is getting called after the method handling the notification.

Any way to stall the execution of the method handling the notification until the UIWebView is loaded or until viewDidLoad finishes execution?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just call the notification handler after the view gets initialized? The notification should be registered after viewDidLoad is complete so that it only gets called after view is loaded.

Comment: how do I do that? I am assigning the notification handler in awakeFromNib. Are you saying that if I assign the notification handler in viewDidLoad, the notification will be forwarded to the handler after viewDidLoad happens?

Comment: I tried assigning the handler in viewDidLoad, but it doesn't work then, because the notification is being generated in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, and at that point viewDidLoad hasn't run yet, so the handler will not handle the notification that gets generated.

Comment: so -- when the applicationDidFinishLaunching, you already know that you have a notification, right? So, why use NotificationCenter at all? Maybe I'm not understanding your original question.

Comment: when the applicationDidFinishLaunching, I might not always have a notification. I only have a notification if the person launched the app from the notification message. If the person launched the app normally, then the applicationDidFinishLaunching will get called, but I do not want to handle the notification. When I DO have a notification, I want to run code in the controller, which is why I'm using notification center. Workflow goes: notification -> hit launch -> applicationDidFinishLaunching -> generate notification that pushNotification is present -> execute code in viewController

Comment: I guess I could add a bool in the viewcontroller that gets set if I have a notification pending, and execute the code in viewDidLoad if the bool is yes... cool thanks for the answer.

Comment: I see. so, when your application enters from background state, your view may never have been loaded in the first place. I would suggest you just set a variable somewhere and read it when your view loads.

Comment: yup thank you that's a good solution!

Comment: One alternative would be to use NSNotificationQueues that would delay the posting of the notification until the current runloop is idle.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `UIWebViewDelegate` and set the UIWebView delegate as self.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
 //handle notification here

}
```

**`webViewDidFinishLoad`**:

Sent after a web view finishes loading a frame.

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
```

Comment: how do i handle the notification in webViewDidFinishLoad? the notification is posted in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions thus: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"pushNotificationAnswerCall" object:nil userInfo:remoteNotification];
and the notification handler is being assigned in awakeFromNib thus:
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(callAnswered:) name:@"pushNotificationAnswerCall" object:nil];